# Jekyll GitHub blog page not found

Tags: ruby, github, jekyll, github-pages

There is open-source GitHub pages site http://spring-ug.github.io/beijing/ with sources at https://github.com/spring-ug/beijing (I am organizing Spring UG and JUG)

[One page](https://github.com/spring-ug/beijing/blob/gh-pages/_posts/2014-05-17-The%20first%20meet%20of%20cloud%20foundry%20Beijing%20by%20Bo%20Yang%20IBM.md) (I am sorry for content grammar) can't be accessed once after site is published http://spring-ug.github.io/beijing/news/events/2014/05/17/The+first+meet+of+cloud+foundry+Beijing+by+Bo+Yang+IBM.html -> 404

I carefully compareed content with [other pages](https://github.com/spring-ug/beijing/tree/gh-pages/_posts) , but can't see why.

**Why Jekyll 1 jekyll post page may be different?**

Comment: This works: http://spring-ug.github.io/beijing/news/events/2014/05/17/The%20first%20meet%20of%20cloud%20foundry%20Beijing%20by%20Bo%20Yang%20IBM.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem was spaces in .md file name.